# UIButton's imageView becomes unhidden when resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Consider the following code. Testing on iOS 7.1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [button setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.imageView.hidden = YES;
    [button sizeToFit];
    NSLog(button.imageView.hidden ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    //button's imageView is no longer hidden!
}
```

Why would sizeToFit unhide the imageView?

Comment: I ran your code an i am getting Yes from NSLog.  Are you still seeing the image on top of the button?  You don't want to hide the button just the image, right?

Comment: @Yan Correct. I'm seeing NO. What version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: It's Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS SDK 7.1

Comment: Note that you **must** set an image for this to be reproduced.

Comment: Yeah that is what i am trying now.  Will let you know in a minute.

Comment: Yes you are right when i set the imageView to an image then sizeToFit will unhide it.  Actually same thing happen if you do button.imageView.alpha = 0.0; and then sizeToFit the image is also unhidden.  I guess it make sense sizeToFit has to unhide the imageView to work otherwise it would resize to 0,0.  When object is hidden its being treated like its not there.   I am not sure if there is an answer in the documentation for this behavior.

Comment: @Yan I've looked through the UIButton documentation and I didn't find anything.

Comment: Yep I was reading it also sizeToFit doesn't mention anything about unhiding views but it does make sense.  Very interesting that a function would change the state of a view.  It should just resize it to nothing in this case and not to unhide the view.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to hide the image by changing the setImage property to nil like -

```
[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of setting hidden=YES and than resizing the button manually.

Comment: Also, this will affect any sizing code that is using the image.